# Import external table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, polybase, sql-server-2019

I created an external table using `polybase` with

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ext].[gendertable]
( 
        gender_id TINYINT NOT NULL,
        gender VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
) 
WITH 
( 
    LOCATION = '/MovieDB/gender.csv', 
    DATA_SOURCE = AzureBlobHDP, 
    FILE_FORMAT = csvformat0
);
GO
```

The data source is `HADOOP`. Is there a way to import this table without defining data type *again* for every column? I search for some code [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/load-data-wideworldimportersdw):

```
CREATE TABLE [mov].[gendertable]
WITH
( 
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
AS
SELECT * FROM [ext].[gendertable]
```

Of course this code fails for me, since I do not use an Azure SQL DW (I get a Syntax error). I use SQL Server 2019 on a VM.

My question is there is a `SQL` expression, such that I do not have to declare the data type for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is quite simple:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [mov].gendertable
FROM [ext].[gendertable];
GO
```